# Prize distribution algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I have written an algorithm for prize distribution for my tournaments. I just want to know if anyone can see any bug or edge case that I haven't figured out or even write something better and more efficient.
So assuming that at the end of a tournament players get a final scores and based on their score they will be sorted and ranked for example:

```
Rank   Score    %total prize
1        50      40%
2        50      25%
3        40      15%
4        20      10%
5        20      5%
6        16      3%
7        10      2%
```

I want it be in a way that in case of tie of Rank A and Rank B, the prize of these ranked be summed and divided by 2 OR in case of tie between Rank A,Rank B and C the sum of these ranks prizes divide by 3 , etc. If there is no tie between ranks they get their predefined prize. so here is the pseudo code for what I have written so far:

```
rank=0
while(rank < Max # prizes)
{
  prize= %prizeForRank(rank)
  offset=1
  while(scoreList[rank+offset]!=null && scoreList[rank]==scoreList[rank+offset])
  {
     prize += %prizeForRank(rank+offset)
     offset++
  }
  prize= prize / offset
  for(int k=0; k<offset;k++)
  {
    prizeOfPlayer[k+rank] = prize
  }
  rank+=offset
}
```

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me.  What you have posted as *pseudocode* smells far too much of C or one of its relatives for my liking and looks too much like code that hasn't been finished; I'm not really understanding why you haven't just finished coding it.  Then again, I'm not really sure what on-topic question you are asking.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I want to know if there is a better way of writing this. This solution is O(n^2). Also yes you are right I'm not good at writing pseudocode I just wanted to write something that other programmers can understand without paying attention to syntax

Comment: I don't understand why the numbers 1 and 2, both having a score of 50, get 40% and 25% respecively.

Comment: You're worrying about the asymptotic complexity of a method which will take about a nano-crotchet to compute for even the largest tournaments.  Yeah, I know we're all concerned with efficiency but sometimes it's just not that important and there really are better things for you to spend time on.  But hey SO is (almost) a free country.

Comment: @GolezTrol the prize column shows the default prize distribution for that rank (if there is no tie). but in my example rank1 and rank2 have same price the the prize distribution should be  (40+25)/2

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark haha thanks anyways just wanted to learn better solutions.

Comment: A single pass over a sorted list of numbers should be able to adjust your "predefined prizes" (however those are determined) to your "adjusted prizes". I have trouble even imagining what an O(n^2) algorithm for doing so would look like. Do you need a quadratic algorithm to tell that "aaaaabbcdddd" breaks into 4 a followed by 2 b followed by a c followed by 3 d?